# How to call PowerShell script to connect azure

Tags: c#, azure, powershell, c#-7.0

[image]I am facing an issue while connecting to Azure through the power shell.
could you please help me to resolve the issue?
code is below, please tell me where I am making a mistake.

we are using .net 7.0 to execute power shell and connect to azure

```
 using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.PowerShell;

namespace ConsoleApppowershell
{
    internal class ConsoleApppowershell
    {
        private static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string _state = "Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope LocalMachine Get-ExecutionPolicy";
            InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
            //iss.ImportPSModule(new string[] { "AzureAD" });
            iss.ExecutionPolicy = ExecutionPolicy.Unrestricted;
            iss.ExecutionPolicy = (ExecutionPolicy)ExecutionPolicyScope.CurrentUser;
            iss.ThrowOnRunspaceOpenError = false;
            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss);
            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create(runspace);
            runspace.Open();
            ps.AddScript(_state).Invoke();
            //await ps.AddScript("Get-ExecutionPolicy").InvokeAsync();
            await ps.AddParameter("-ExecutionPolicy", "Unrestricted").InvokeAsync();
            //await ps.AddScript("Install-Module -Name AzureAD -Force").InvokeAsync();
            await ps.AddScript("Import-Module -Name AzureAD -UseWindowsPowerShell").InvokeAsync();
            //PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create(runspace);
            ps.AddCommand("Connect-AzureAD");
            ps.AddParameters(new Dictionary<string,[![enter image description here][1]][1]object>
            {

                ["ApplicationId "] = " ",

                ["CertificateThumbprint"] = " ",

                ["TenantId"] = " "

            });
            Collection<PSObject> connectionResult = ps.Invoke();
            ps.Commands.Clear();
            ps.AddCommand("Get-AzureADGroup");
            ps.AddParameter("Filter", "DisplayName eq 'O365_ENTERPRISE_E5_DEVELOPER'");
            Collection<PSObject> results = ps.Invoke();
            if (!ps.HadErrors)
            {
                foreach (PSObject result in results)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (ErrorRecord error in ps.Streams.Error)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(error.ToString());
                }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The path of the cmdlets are not found (or cmdlet is not installed).  Try using fullpath of the cmdlets : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Connect-AzureAd

Comment: Hi Jdweng , Thank you for your replay but i did not understand , could you please explain in details

Comment: Do the commands work if you run them in an interactive PowerShell session? It might be easier to try to eliminate C# as a moving part first if you get the same error interactively...

Comment: PS cmdlets are normally installed in the folder shown in my 1st comment.  The cmdlet may be in other locations on your machine.  Try searching for the cmdlet on you machine to find full path.

Comment: why not use the [c# Graph SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdks-overview) then you don't need powershell at all.. you don't even need the SDK either, can make a call to the [groups API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) using the `HttpClient` class

Answer (score 0):

> How to call PowerShell script to connect azure

I do agree with @jdweng and Alternatively, below is the code how I connect PowerShell with .Net7 and use the azure PowerShell commands with it and i followed [SO-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77754765/unable-to-execute-azure-cli-commands-in-c-sharp-console-application/77756015#77756015):

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
public class RithPowerShellCommandRunner
{
    public static string ExceutePowershellCommand(string command)
    {
        var rith_procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "powershell.exe",
            Arguments = $"-Command \"{command}\"",
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };

        using (var rith_pro = new Process { StartInfo = rith_procStartInfo })
        {
            rith_pro.Start();

            string rith_out = rith_pro.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            string error = rith_pro.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

            rith_pro.WaitForExit();

            if (rith_pro.ExitCode == 0)
            {
                return rith_out;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Hello Rithwik Bojja, execution of command failed and the Error: {error}");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        StringBuilder rith = new StringBuilder();
        rith.AppendLine("Import-Module -Name AzureAD");
        rith.AppendLine("Connect-AzureAD");
        rith.AppendLine("Get-AzureADUser -SearchString 'Test 12'");
        string rithwik_output = ExceutePowershellCommand(rith.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(rithwik_output);
    }
}
```

**`csproj:`**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Cake.Powershell" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Management.Automation" Version="7.3.11" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**`Output:`**

[image]