# Can't import ActiveDirectory module in .NET 8, works in Powershell

Tags: c#, .net, azure, powershell, active-directory

I am trying to run Powershell commands from .NET 8 and I am running into an error:

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

The project has a Nuget package Microsoft.Powershell.SDK installed. I also installed PowerShell Active Directory module through Add features on Windows 11.

I created a console app just to try and open a runspace with the following code:

```
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
...
var initial = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
initial.ExecutionPolicy = Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy.Unrestricted;

initial.ImportPSModule(["ActiveDirectory"]);
using var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initial);

try
{
    runspace.Open();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

**The code works on my colleague's PC**. I tried installing every RSAT package, restarting PC several times, checked that I am using SDK instead of System.Management.Automation Nuget directly. There is a Module ActiveDirectory installed in my system32/WindowsPowershell/v1.0/Modules, I do have .dll files in WinSys folder. I have no problems running whatever I want from Powershell, but .NET does not recognize it exists.

**Update**: I have fixed the error by copying the installed ActiveDirectory module from path above and the dlls to a folder. After that I have imported the folder as a module and it works. I still don't know why wouldn't it find the module on it's own since it is installed correctly.

Comment: You want to run AD Powershell Commands in .net 8? Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. @RithwikBojja

Comment: I assume it was you who created [GitHub issue #21232](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/21232). Per my comment [there](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/21232#issuecomment-1947224834) my sense is that you're dealing with a _bug_ in PowerShell SDK projects using v7.4.1 in combination with .NET 8 - exact cause yet to be determined.

Comment: Yes, it was me. @mklement0 Thanks for linking the issue, just came here to do that too :)

Answer (score 1):

> Run AD Powershell Commands in .net 8? Can't import ActiveDirectory module in .NET 8

I have followed my answer from [SO-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77866394/how-to-call-powershell-script-to-connect-azure/77870639#77870639)  and below is the code which worked for me:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
public class RithwikTest
{
    public static string TestRithwik(string command)
    {
        var rithwik_procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "powershell.exe",
            Arguments = $"-Command \"{command}\"",
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };

        using (var rithwik_pro = new Process { StartInfo = rithwik_procStartInfo })
        {
            rithwik_pro.Start();

            string rith_out1 = rithwik_pro.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            string error = rithwik_pro.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

            rithwik_pro.WaitForExit();

            if (rithwik_pro.ExitCode == 0)
            {
                return rith_out1;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Hello Rithwik Bojja there is an expection, execution of command failed and the Error: {error}");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        StringBuilder rithwik = new StringBuilder();
        rithwik.AppendLine("Import-Module -Name AzureAD");
        rithwik.AppendLine("Connect-AzureAD");
        rithwik.AppendLine("Get-AzureADUser -SearchString 'Quality System'");
        string rith_output = TestRithwik(rithwik.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(rith_output);
    }
}
```

**`csproj:`**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Management.Automation" Version="7.4.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

**`Edit:`**

As you mentioned you want with your code `var initial = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();`

Below is the csproj which worked for it:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Diagnostics" Version="7.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management" Version="7.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility" Version="7.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost" Version="7.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WSMan.Management" Version="7.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Management.Automation" Version="7.4.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention the given code works on my colleague's PC. I see you are including System.Management.Automation directly, which is not recommended according to this:
https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8625#issuecomment-456515037

Comment: Not sure why its given not recommended, but this works fine and expected, I usually use this method only. If the code works, in your colleague, the issue might be the location of Ad dll in the console application.

Comment: I appreciate the effort and thank you for the alternative, but I cannot refactor the code just because it does not work on my PC.

Comment: Since it can't find Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management, I copied .dlls into bin and obj folders and rebuilt the project. Still the same error

Comment: I have given the csproj that worked for me for your given code

Comment: Please check my latest update to the post

Comment: I am glad that it started working after installing it again

Comment: @NaveenSharma The given solution is an alternative. It did not fix my problem, nor is my problem really fixed. I have found a work-around but that is it.